# The meaning of Isaiah 43:9

Tags: isaiah

In Isaiah 43:9 it says:

> כׇּֽל־הַגּוֹיִ֞ם נִקְבְּצ֣וּ יַחְדָּ֗ו וְיֵאָֽסְפוּ֙ לְאֻמִּ֔ים מִ֤י בָהֶם֙ יַגִּ֣יד זֹ֔את וְרִאשֹׁנ֖וֹת יַשְׁמִיעֻ֑נוּ יִתְּנ֤וּ עֵֽדֵיהֶם֙ וְיִצְדָּ֔קוּ וְיִשְׁמְע֖וּ וְיֹאמְר֥וּ אֱמֶֽת׃

> “Let all the nations be gathered together, and let the peoples be assembled: who among them can declare this, and show us former things? let them bring their witnesses, that they may be justified; or let them hear, and say, It is truth.” (Isaiah 43:9, ASV)

This verse is constructed of 4 parts.

First part is about the gathering, which is very clear. The other three parts are very cryptic.

I ask for the overall meaning of this verse with emphasis on

- "declare this"? I mean, "this" refering to what?
- "let them hear, and say, It is truth"? What will they hear?
- Are those who bring their witnesses the same body as those who hear and say "it is truth"?

Comment: The answer to both questions is Isa 43:1-7.  That is the "this" and the "truth".

Comment: @Dottard No no  there is no relation. Verse 9 seems independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isaiah 43 describes why the Israelites are the chosen people:

- 1–4: God protects the Israelites.
- 5–7: Eventually the Israelites will be united again.
- 8–9: The combined testimony of all the Gentiles could not provide truth.
- 10–13: Israel alone was chosen to record and bear witness to God's truth.

> “**You are My witnesses**,” says the LORD,
> “And My servant **whom I have chosen**,
> That you may know and believe Me,
> And understand that I am He.
> Before Me there was no God formed,
> Nor shall there be after Me.
> I, even I, am the LORD,
> And besides Me there is no savior.
> I have declared and saved,
> I have proclaimed,
> And **there was no foreign god among you**;
> Therefore **you are My witnesses**,”
> Says the LORD, “**that I am God**.
> Indeed before the day was, I am He;
> And there is no one who can deliver out of My hand;
> I work, and who will reverse it?”
> — Isaiah 10–13 (NKJV)

As for verse 9 specifically, looking at [various translations](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/isa/43/1/t_bibles_722009) would help understand it better.

For instance, NLT (my formatting) translates it as:

> Gather the nations together!
> Assemble the peoples of the world!
>
> - Which of their idols has ever foretold such things?
> - Which can predict what will happen tomorrow?
> - Where are the witnesses of such predictions?
> - Who can verify that they spoke the truth?

The first two lines set up a hypothetical situation where all the knowledge of the world is assembled together.

The remaining four lines ask rhetorical questions that imply that no one can provide the knowledge that has been entrusted to Israel.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, can you please focus on the interpretation of verse 9?